# converting vim snippets in imap error

Tags: vim

I have some `snippets` in `vim`(Using `Ultisnips`) as:

```
snippet prg 
!This is file : `!v expand('%:r')`
! Author= `!v expand($USER)`
! Started at: `date +%d.%m.%y`
! 
Program  ${1:`!v expand('%:r')`}
Implicit None
${2:<++Start Typing++>}
End Program  $1
endsnippet
```

I am trying to have the same effect with imap.
I have tried to write the map as:

```
:inoremap `foo ! Program <C-r>=expand('%:r')<CR><CR>! Author     :<C-R>=$USER <CR><CR>! Date      :<C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR><CR>Program  <C-r>=${1:expand('%:r')}Implicit None<CR>${2:<++Start Typing++>}End Program  $1
```

But `<C-r>` is unable to process the placeholders like `${1:expand('%:r')}` and not working as intended.
What I am doing wrong here?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

A mapping just converts trigger character(s) into different characters. To have the placeholder functionality, especially with placeholder mirroring and *update as you type*, you really need to use a (quite complex) plugin like UltiSnips or snipMate.

Best you can have with built-ins (and I would prefer an `:iabbreviate` instead of `:imap`, as the former doesn't have the delayed insertion of characters until the full mapping uniquely matches):

```
:inoremap `foo ! Program <C-r>=expand('%:r')<CR><CR>! Author     :<C-R>=$USER <CR><CR>! Date      :<C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR><CR>Program  <C-r>=expand('%:r')<CR><CR>Implicit None<CR><CR>End Program<Up><End>
```